# Steps of the MMP "in family"

Tags: birational-geometry, divisors, minimal-model-program, contraction-mapping

Let $\pi\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism between irreducible varieties with terminal singularities (let us say smooth if you want). I suppose that I have an open subset $U$ of $Y$ over which the fibres are smooth, and I then restrict to $X_U\to U$. Is it possible to do steps of the MMP on $X_U\to U$ if you know that they work on each fibre?

More precisely:

a) let $D\subset X_U$ be an irreducible divisor such that the restriction of each fibre $F$ is a union of disjoint divisors, each of them can be contracted by a divisorial contraction. Can we infer that we can contract $D$ and get a morphism $X_U\to Y_U$ over $U$ doing the job on each fibre?

b) Similarly, if $D\subset X_U$ is an irreducible closed subset such that the restriction to each fibre is the disjoint union of subsets that can be flopped, can I do the flop globally?

I would be happy if the answer was yes, even if some conditions, easy to check in precise cases, have to be fullfilled. Indeed, I would like to apply this to as sequence of examples where I am pretty sure that it works, but would like to have a general argument instead of doing case by case the study of $X$, and restrict simply to fibres, which are easy to handle in my case.

Comment: Jeremy -- I don't remember the exact answer (and I am not 100% sure what the precise statement you need is) but of the top of my head, but I think this should be fine as long as we have that $(X,D)$ is say lc and log smooth over the base. Then by Corollary 1.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1186.pdf, sections will extend from fibers to the total space. This should give you what you want (eg. components of $D$ are contracted by the mmp iff this happens when restricted to the fibers).